# Redefine const in golang for test

Tags: unit-testing, testing, go

I'm writing an http client for a service and for testing I want to use a `net/http/httptest` server instead of calling out to the remote API.  I can easily do this if I make the `baseUrl` a global variable which gets set to the url of my test server. However, this makes the production code more fragile because `baseUrl` can also be changed during runtime.  My preference would be to make `baseUrl` a `const` for production code but still be able to change.

```
package main
const baseUrl = "http://google.com"

// in main_test.go
ts := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  ...
 }
const baseUrl = ts.URL
// above line throws const baseUrl already defined error
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If your code uses a const value, it is not *testing-friendly* (regarding testing with different values of that parameter).

You could approach your problem with a slight refactoring. Let's say you have a function that uses this const:

```
const baseUrl = "http://google.com"

func MyFunc() string {
    // use baseUrl
}
```

You could create another function that takes base URL as a parameter, and your original `MyFunc()` calls this:

```
const baseUrl_ = "http://google.com"

func MyFunc() string {
    // Call other function passing the const value
    return myFuncImpl(baseUrl_)
}

func myFuncImpl(baseUrl string) string {
    // use baseUrl
    // Same implementation that was in your original MyFunc() function
}
```

This way the API of your library doesn't change, but now you can test the functionality of your original `MyFunc()` by testing `myFuncImpl()`, and you can pass any value to test with.

Calling `MyFunc()` will remain safe as it always passes the const `baseUrl_` to `myFuncImpl()` where the implementation now resides. It's your decision whether you make this new `myFuncImpl()` function exported or not; it may remain unexported as testing code may (should) be placed in the same package and can call it without problems.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I ended up dropping the const, adding a global `var testServer *httptest.Server` and a `func getURL() string` that checks if testServer is nil.  Logic being, it's less likely production code will set a testServer then accidentally mutate a global string var